# JPA Insert statement is not passing validation

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA INSERT @Query that does not pass hibernate validation. I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.10.RELEASE.

When I run a JUnit test the HQL validation is failing with:

> org.hibernate.QueryException:
> could not resolve property:  of: Person

```
@Embeddable
public class Name {

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String first;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Name name;

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query( "INSERT INTO Person (name.first, name.last) select 'first', 'last' from Dual")
    void insert();

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to write an insert statement if you have JPA?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the insert statement is to insert records from one table to another, the example is just a simplified example to recreate the exception I am getting. The original statement has a select from another table.

Comment: Ok but why do you use a JpaRespository for that? This would be much easier with a JdbcTemplate

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes I could, this was existing code that we added an embedded object to so was trying not make to many other changes. Just wondering why it won't work using HQL

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not know INSERT statements.

You have to set the attribute nativeQuery to true:

```
@Modifying
@Query("INSERT INTO Person (name.first, name.last) select 'first', 'last' from Dual", 
       nativeQuery=true)
void insert();
```

Comment: I don't think that is true as the insert works if I remove the embedded object.